# How can I get Velocity to output a greater than / less than without escaping it?

Tags: character-encoding, escaping, special-characters, velocity

I'm trying to get Velocity to output the following Javascript code:

```
if ((whichOne+1) <= numCallouts ) {
whichOne = whichOne + 1; } else {
whichOne = 1;
     }
```

Whenever I try to get Velocity to print a > or a <, it represents it as a & gt; or & lt;, which doesn't help me since I'm trying to get it to produce Javascript. I've tried:

```
#set ( $gt = ">" )
```

But even that ends up as a & gt;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So when you do `#set ( $gt = ">" )` and then `$gt` you end up with `&gt;`? It doesn't do that for me, it outputs ">". Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a default behavior, the only reason I can think of why this is happening is if you have event `ReferenceInsertionEventHandler` configured with `EscapeHtmlReference` either in your `velocity.config` or in the Velocity initialization code.

Here is [more info about events](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Event_Handlers)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with Velocity - however, the problem is that I was using Velocity as an third party embedded language, and didn't have access to change the Velocity settings.

Unfortunately the only solution I was able to find was to rewrite the code without using greater than/less than explicitly, which admittedly is awful, but it's all about getting it to work...

Here is an example workaround for conditionals where you are trying to see if one number is larger than another:

```
if (n1 > n2) //Doesn't work because velocity turns this into if (n1 &gt; n2)

if (n1 != n2)
{
    diff = n1 - n2;
    abs = abs(n1 - n2);
    if (diff / abs == 1) //Greater than
    else //if == -1 then less than
}
else //Equal
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are able to use the alternate symbols as described here :

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html#aifelseifelse_-_Output_conditional_on_truth_of_statements

So try to use `if (n1 gt n2)`.